# Check field value through 2 methods

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a Report which i want to check on if a certain field on the SalesLine table is filled, if so, show the value of this field.

I have 2 custom tables which the report is using.

`Table A` & `Table B`

`Table A`, has a method with the following query:

```
select firstonly Id from TableB
        where TableB.Id == this.Id;
return TableB.Id;
```

`Table B`, has a method with the following code:

```
public SalesLine salesLine()
{
    return SalesLine::findInventTransId(this.InventTransId);
}
```

Now I need to check on the report, throughout these 2 methods, if `Field X` on the Sales Line table is filled. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: select firstonly Id,InventTransId from TableB
        where TableB.Id == this.Id;
return TableB.salesLine().Fieldx ? TableB.Id : 0 ;

Comment: This is what i needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify table A method as below.

```
select firstonly Id,InventTransId from TableB where TableB.Id == this.Id; 
return TableB.salesLine().Fieldx ? TableB.Id : 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question seems to obvious to me...so maybe you're not asking your question correctly:

```
if(TableB.salesLine().FieldX)
    info("FieldX is filled");
```

Comment: Probably i haven't given enough information:

Table A is the header and Table B contains multiple lines of the header. Therefore i have made the first query, to find the first or, one line in Table B, and based on that line in Table B, look for the SalesLine based on the InventTransId.